# Add Points to Choropleth Map in ggplot2

Tags: r, maps, ggplot2

I'm looking at the following example from Hadley Wickham's `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
states<-map_data("state")
arrests<-USArrests
names(arrests)<-tolower(names(arrests))
arrests$region<-tolower(rownames(USArrests))

chloro<-merge(states, arrests, by="region")
chloro<-chloro[order(chloro$order), ]
qplot(long, lat, data=chloro, group=group, fill = assault, geom="polygon")
```

I would then like to add points for some notable US cities to the map, but I haven't been able to. I've tried:

```
base_map<-qplot(long, lat, data=chloro, group=group, fill = assault, geom="polygon")
base_map + qplot(long, lat, data=us.cities) + borders("state", size=.5)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in p + o : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.ggplot", "Ops.data.frame") for "+""
```

How can I add these points?

Comment: Did you mean to include the `qplot` using `us.cities` in the last line, or is that a copy+paste error? Because when I remove that, it runs just fine.

Comment: I need us.cities, because I'm trying to add those points to the graphic

Comment: If I remove qplot, and replace it with geom_point(aes(long, lat), data=us.cities), I get an error that says 'assault' not found

Comment: because you haven't unmapped group or fill with `NULL` but doing this doesn't overlay the cities so I'm actually curious on this solution myself

Comment: @TylerRinker That's funny, switching to `geom_point` and unampping those two aesthetics seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: @joran you are correct.  the problem was HI and AK.  I knew it wasn't plotting correctly but it was just that it was including cities for which there was no map space. `us.cities[!us.cities$country.etc %in% c("HI", "AK"), ]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work just fine for me:

```
base_map + 
    geom_point(aes(long, lat,fill = NULL,group = NULL), size = 1,data=us.cities) + 
    borders("state", size=.5)
```

Although you may want to exclude the cities in HI and AK, as I did to produce this version of the plot:

[image]