# When should I use geom_map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, choropleth

I'm making a choropleth map with added points in ggplot. 
So, following the last example of the [geom_map help docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/geom_map.html)

I came up with this:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(maps)

set.seed(47)
county_map <- map_data("county", "washington")
names(county_map)[5:6] <- c("state", "id")
countyData <- data.frame(id = unique(county_map$id), value = rnorm(39)) 
map1 <- ggplot(countyData, aes(map_id = id)) +
    geom_map(aes(fill = value), map = county_map, colour = "black") +
    coord_map() +
    expand_limits(x = county_map$long, y = county_map$lat)

print(map1)
```

which works great for the choropleth map. (Aside that I'm thrilled with the `map_data` function.) But then I try and add points

```
pointData <- structure(list(xx = c(-119.872483243387, -122.809038239929, 
-122.143143065312
), yy = c(48.1320425447619, 46.7352071436801, 47.9911548514037
)), .Names = c("xx", "yy"), row.names = c(1746L, 7281L, 2692L
), class = "data.frame")

map1 + geom_point(mapping = aes(xx, yy), data = pointData)
```

And I can't get it to work. I  tried a lot of variations, setting `group` to `NULL`, naming `aes` arguments, etc. No luck. So I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12341281/903061) which does the exact same thing without a problem by merging the map data with the choropleth data and using `geom_polygon`, which seems more straightforward anyway. (It took me a little while to work out the ID mapping in the first place because I didn't realize I had to remove the `region` column name to successfully use `id`. And the syntax of the first method still seems weird to me.)

So, two questions:

1. How is it possible to add points from a different data frame using the method shown above with `geom_map`?
2. More importantly, are there any advantages to using `geom_map` as opposed to the `geom_polygon` approach?

Comment: `geom_map` will usually be much faster than `geom_polygon` because it can do the merging in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that `ggplot` has no way to tie your point data to the map. Looking at your data frames, you have this for your map:

```
str(countyData)
'data.frame':   39 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id   : chr  "adams" "asotin" "benton" "chelan" ...
 $ value: num  1.995 0.711 0.185 -0.282 0.109 ...
```

...and this for your points:

```
str(pointData)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ xx: num  -120 -123 -122
 $ yy: num  48.1 46.7 48
```

Do you see any common variables there that would allow `ggplot` to locate your points?

Still, the problem is easily resolved. I typically use `geom_polygon` rather than `geom_map` but that's largely out of habit. This works, for example:

```
colnames(pointData) <- c('long','lat') # makes consistent with county_map
pointData$group <- 1 # ggplot needs a group to work with
county_map$value <- sapply(1:nrow(county_map),
                           function(x) round(runif(1, 1, 8), 0)) # for colours

ggplot(county_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(aes(fill = value)) +
    coord_map() +
    geom_point(data = pointData, aes(x = long, y = lat), shape = 21, fill = "red")
```

Which gives the following (note the points).
[image: screenshot]

However, as to whether you should use `geom_map` or `geom_polygon`, I have not really thought about the issue much. Maybe somebody else has a view.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me :

```
map1 <- ggplot(countyData) +
  geom_map( map = county_map, aes(map_id = id,fill = value), 
            colour = "black") + coord_map() +
  expand_limits(x = county_map$long, y = county_map$lat)
  map1 + geom_point(mapping = aes(xx, yy), data = pointData)
```

For me `geom_map` is a wrapper of a `geom_polygon`. It is a layer that contains all geographical settings (lat and long grouped by id).

I would use `geom_map` when I plot a map and `geom_polygon` to plot any polygon type.

**EDIT**
 To add the map

[image]