# understanding ggplot2 geom_map map_id

Tags: r, ggplot2

This comes from the ggplot2 documentation:

```
# Better example
crimes <- data.frame(state = tolower(rownames(USArrests)), USArrests)
library(reshape2) # for melt
crimesm <- melt(crimes, id = 1)
if (require(maps)) {
  states_map <- map_data("state")
  ggplot(crimes, aes(map_id = state)) + geom_map(aes(fill = Murder), map = states_map) + expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat)
  last_plot() + coord_map()
  ggplot(crimesm, aes(map_id = state)) + geom_map(aes(fill = value), map = states_map) + expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat) + facet_wrap( ~ variable)
}
```

I don't understand how this can work since there is no common identifier in the `states_map` data frame which uses "region" to name the states column and the `crimes` data frame which labels the states, "states." What ties the data to the map?

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698616/when-should-i-use-geom-map) the poster renames the columns of the map data frame to conform with the data but the ggplot2 documentation doesn't seem to do it.  How?  When I rename the columns of `states_map` in the example above, so that "state" is common to both data frames, it breaks the code.

```
crimes <- data.frame(state = tolower(rownames(USArrests)), USArrests)
library(reshape2) # for melt
crimesm <- melt(crimes, id = 1)
if (require(maps)) {
  states_map <- map_data("state")
##### my attempt to fix what isn't broken #################
names(states_map)[5]<-"state"
###########################################################
  ggplot(crimes, aes(map_id = state)) + geom_map(aes(fill = Murder), map = states_map) + expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat)
  last_plot() + coord_map()
 # Error: all(c("x", "y", "id") %in% names(map)) is not TRUE
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the code for `geom_map`:

```
function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", ..., 
    map, na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) 
{
    stopifnot(is.data.frame(map))
    if (!is.null(map$lat)) 
        map$y <- map$lat
    if (!is.null(map$long)) 
        map$x <- map$long
    if (!is.null(map$region)) 
        map$id <- map$region
    stopifnot(all(c("x", "y", "id") %in% names(map)))

# etcetera...
}
```

This means, that for the correct building of the geom, a data frame `map` will be generated with x, y, and id column. With `aes(map_id = state)` you are basically assigning `crimes$state` to `map$id` (to my understanding)

If you don't have an `id` column in your map data, the column which is called `region` will be used as your id column. 
You can test this with changing the name of `states_map$region` to `states_map$id`

```
names(states_map)[5]<-"id"
```

This works with the given example.